# Understanding garbage collection in C

Tags: c

I decided to rewrite what I was doing going backwards to basics:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  int d;
  printf("ta-dah: %i %i %i %i\n", a, b, c, d);

  return 0;
}
```

I call it `me.c` and I compile it with `gcc me.c` and run it with `./a.out`.

I get this as a result:

```
hc$ ./a.out 
ta-dah: 32767 1477090280 0 0
```

This is a very simple program, and I am not sure where the error is. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is not a "stupid C program". It's a very basic programming error caused by not initializing variables before reading from them. The problem is not C. :-)

Comment: Why do you think there's an error?

Comment: There are no stupid C programs just...

Comment: Why this question has been closed to be "not a real question????" it has been a fundamental question for me today and I am pretty sure people that do not know c garbage-memory-related issues can learn from this.

Comment: @haskellguy Do everyone and yourself a favor, pick up a decent book on C and learn the language. That would be way smarter than calling a program stupid and making unreasonable assumptions about what you have no idea of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-static variables (local variables) are indeterminate. Reading them prior to assigning a value results in undefined behavior.

Either initialize the variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  int c = 3;
  int d = 4;
  printf("ta-dah: %i %i %i %i\n", a, b, c, d);

  return 0;
}
```

Output: `ta-dah: 1 2 3 4`

Or set them to static:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

  static int a;
  static int b;
  static int c;
  static int d;
  printf("ta-dah: %i %i %i %i\n", a, b, c, d);

  return 0;
}
```

Output: `ta-dah: 0 0 0 0`

Comment: can you express what will exactly be the difference and when I should use one or the other?

Comment: Yes, one you assign the variables a value right away, which can be altered later.  The other doesn't really assign anything to the variable, but makes sure random gibberish isn't assigned to the variable so you can easily manipulate it later.

Answer (score 4):

You dont initialize the values, so it prints garbage values (whatever happens to be on the stack memory at that point in (memory)spacetime.

You should initialize them first, if you want to be able to read from them.

```
int a = 3; 
int b = 42;
int c = 1337;
int d = 0;
```

[Example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1RAXBG%241)

Comment: +1, but I'd rephrase "might want to" to "absolutely must without exception". :-) @haskellguy: No, you don't, if you initialize them as shown **before** you `printf()` them.

Comment: @haskellguy http://liveworkspace.org/code/1RAXBG$1

Answer (score 1):

Unless you initialize the variables with values you will see whatever value happens to be at the memory address used to store the variable's value.

Change it to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  int c = 3;
  int d = 4;

  printf("ta-dah: %i %i %i %i\n", a, b, c, d);

  return 0;
}
```

And you will get:

```
ta-dah: 1 2 3 4
```